# Do antimagic fields work on Dredmor?

Tags: dungeons-of-dredmor

I have a Warrior/Rogue-heavy character that has gotten down to the bottom floor once now. When I got there, Dredmor used a spell that killed me after one or two rounds.

I'm considering adding [Emomancy](http://www.dredmorwiki.com/wiki/Emomancy) into the mix so I can get *Dampening Field of Angst* (the antimagic field). Since I play on perma-death, I can't easily test this. I don't want to waste a skill slot for a single spell that might not even work.

Does this spell affect him, or does he resist it like the final boss in most games?

Answer (score 3):

#### 1.0.9

In 1.0.9, there are [reports](http://community.gaslampgames.com/threads/lord-dredmor-2-0.2798/) that Dredmor was susceptible to anti-magic.  I haven't personally made it down to Dredmor (I too play perma-death) to verify with the current build.

#### 1.0.11

Since then Playing non-perma-death at patch level 1.0.11 with both Emomancy (Dampening field of Angst) and Magic Training (License to Cast), both of these anti-magic skills work as anti-magic on Dredmor.  In each case the debuff was in effect, Dredmor was unable to cast spells.

Some considerations.  The license to cast does damage and has a 14 turn cool down (15 turn long effect).  Dampening field of angst is a 3x3 area effect, no damage, no cool down, lasts 15 turns and the area effect lasts 24 turns.

There have been no apparent changes since this time.

Answer (score 0):

Silencing Dredmor is a time-honored way of making him less powerful -- OR IS IT?  If he can't cast at you, he'll advance on you much faster and punch you in the face much more, and his punches HURT.  In many cases it's actually better to get really high Magic Reflect (2x Mirror Darkly?) and let him waste his turns spamming spells at you while you sit safely back and hit him with Holy Hand Grenades and Clockwork Sawblades. :)